# Not able to read train data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

After reading `"train.csv"` data into a variable, when I try to print the first five rows with `train.head()`, it is gives me an error.

My code is:

```
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv",  dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})
train.head()
```

And once I run it, I receive the error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 train.head()
>
> NameError: name 'train' is not defined

Comment: what does `train` simply give?

Comment: Did you import correctly, are paths correct?

Comment: yes when i am loading data to train variable it does not give any error but when i am trying to print first five rows or when trying to get info related to train it gives NameError

Comment: Could you provide what `locals()` returns after `pd.read_csv(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what went wrong but try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv(r'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv',  dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})
print(train.head())
```

I get:

```
>>>              street        city    zip state  beds  baths  sq__ft  \
>>> 0      3526 HIGH ST  SACRAMENTO  95838    CA     2      1     836   
>>> 1       51 OMAHA CT  SACRAMENTO  95823    CA     3      1    1167   
>>> 2    2796 BRANCH ST  SACRAMENTO  95815    CA     2      1     796   
>>> 3  2805 JANETTE WAY  SACRAMENTO  95815    CA     2      1     852   
>>> 4   6001 MCMAHON DR  SACRAMENTO  95824    CA     2      1     797   
>>> 
>>>           type                     sale_date  price   latitude   longitude  
>>> 0  Residential  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  59222  38.631913 -121.434879  
>>> 1  Residential  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  68212  38.478902 -121.431028  
>>> 2  Residential  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  68880  38.618305 -121.443839  
>>> 3  Residential  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  69307  38.616835 -121.439146  
>>> 4  Residential  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  81900  38.519470 -121.435768
```

Hope it helped

Comment: this thing always work and give first five rows of data  . . .i have not encountered this error before .. . i am using goole cloud ...                                                                       i have used this "! chmod u+rwx train.csv"  command before reading train.. .  dont konw what is it doing

Comment: don't know much about linux but `chmod` changes file premissions. maybe it has somthing to do with bad file premissions

Comment: If the problem was with permissions pd.read_csv probably would raised IOError.